# How to use webdriver package in flutter

Tags: flutter, automation, webautomation

How to use the package [web_driver](https://pub.dev/packages/webdriver) in flutter to automate websites on android.

Comment: Can you please mention what do you want to automate precisely ?

Comment: I want to automate website in android . @user18520267